# Errors in updating titanium

Tags: titanium, npm, titanium-alloy

I have installed titanium in ubuntu 12.10. However as I try to install updates for Titanium CLI, Node.ACS and Alloy, I received the following errors:

```
Failed to get value of npm config key prefix: npm ERR! Error: EACCES, mkdir '/home/ralf/Titanium_Studio/[sudo] password for ralf: /home/ralf/Titanium_Studio/[sudo] password for ralf: /home/ralf/Titanium_Studio/[sudo] password for ralf: /home/ralf/Titanium_Studio'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, mkdir '/home/ralf/Titanium_Studio/[sudo] password for ralf: /home/ralf/Titanium_Studio/[sudo] password for ralf: /home/ralf/Titanium_Studio/[sudo] password for ralf: /home/ralf/Titanium_Studio']
npm ERR!   errno: 3,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   path: '/home/ralf/Titanium_Studio/[sudo] password for ralf: /home/ralf/Titanium_Studio/[sudo] password for ralf: /home/ralf/Titanium_Studio/[sudo] password for ralf: /home/ralf/Titanium_Studio' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! System Linux 3.5.0-51-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "config" "get" "prefix"
npm ERR! cwd /home/ralf/Titanium_Studio
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.28
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.9
npm ERR! path /home/ralf/Titanium_Studio/[sudo] password for ralf: /home/ralf/Titanium_Studio/[sudo] password for ralf: /home/ralf/Titanium_Studio/[sudo] password for ralf: /home/ralf/Titanium_Studio
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno 3
npm ERR! stack Error: EACCES, mkdir '/home/ralf/Titanium_Studio/[sudo] password for ralf: /home/ralf/Titanium_Studio/[sudo] password for ralf: /home/ralf/Titanium_Studio/[sudo] password for ralf: /home/ralf/Titanium_Studio'
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/ralf/Titanium_Studio/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

What does this mean? How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Did you run the command as root? (prefixed with `sudo`)?

Comment: No, when I run titanium it always ask me to update. Didn't use the command line interface. But it ask me for my password before it start installing.

Comment: Wait I have already solve my problem. Thanks @Sukima.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run the titanium studio app through this in the command line

```
sudo ./TitaniumStudio
```

instead of clicking the file in its folder.